# Comparing Sizes of Multiple Lists

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

Let's say I have multiple lists:

```
A = [1]
B = [3, 2]
C = [5, 1, 6]
D = [7, 4, 18]
```

I want to compare the length of the lists, and output longest list of the 4 lists.
So in this case, the output would be:

```
A, D contain the longest list(s).
```

I was thinking of comparing them one by one, but that will be quite hectic and inefficient to type out. Is there any way to do this using a user-defined function?

I'm still quite new to python and I'm going brain dead...

```
def fishing():
    global target_counter
    target_counter = pHands_new[target].count(target_rank)
    global card_counter

    if target_counter >0:
        for i in range(target_counter):
            pHands_new[target].remove(target_rank)
        for i in range(target_counter):
            pHands_new[N].append(target_rank)
        print "*"*70
        print "HIT:", target_counter, "card(s) transferred"
        print "*"*70
        card_counter = pHands_new[N].count(target_rank)
        if card_counter ==4:
            for i in range(card_counter):
                pHands_new[N].remove(target_rank)
            pBooks(N)
    else:
        draw = GetTopCard(sDeck_new)
        if draw == target_rank:
            pHands_new[N].append(draw)
            print "HIT: LUCKILY, You fished up the rank <"+draw+">"
            card_counter = pHands_new[N].count(draw)
            if card_counter ==4:
                for i in range(card_counter):
                    pHands_new[N].remove(draw)
                pBooks(N)

        elif draw != target_rank:
            pHands_new[N].append(draw)
            print "MISS: You fished up the rank <"+draw+">"
            card_counter = pHands_new[N].count(draw)
            if card_counter ==4:
                for i in range(card_counter):
                    pHands_new[N].remove(draw)
                pBooks(N)

def pBooks(player):
        books[player].append(target_rank)
```

Notes:

-pHands_new is a nested list, there are 4 lists within pHands_new

-N is CURRENT player

-target_rank is the card that is targeted of another player

-Books is another nested list. When a player has 4 of the same card/rank, it is removed from the players hand and put into books.

The lists I'm comparing here are books[0] .... books[3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> a = [1]
>>> b = [3, 2]
>>> c = [5, 1, 6]
>>> d = [7, 4, 18]
>>>
>>> max_len = len(max([a,b,c,d], key=len)) # max(map(len, [a,b,c,d]))
>>> lists = {
...     'a': a,
...     'b': b,
...     'c': c,
...     'd': d,
... }
>>> names = [name for name in lists if len(lists[name]) == max_len]
>>> print '{} contain the longest list(s).'.format(', '.join(names))
c, d contain the longest list(s).
```

---

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> b = [3, 2]
>>> c = [5, 1, 6]
>>> d = [7, 4, 18]
>>> 
>>> max_len = len(max([a,b,c,d], key=len)) # max(map(len, [a,b,c,d]))
>>> lists = {
...     'a': a,
...     'b': b,
...     'c': c,
...     'd': d,
... }
>>> names = [name for name in lists if len(lists[name]) == max_len]
>>> print '{} contain the longest list(s).'.format(', '.join(names))
a contain the longest list(s).
```

---

```
books = [
    [1],
    [3, 2],
    [5, 1, 6],
    [7, 4, 18],
]

max_len = len(max(books, key=len)) # max(map(len, books))
names = [str(i+1) for i, bs in enumerate(books) if len(bs) == max_len]
print 'Book {} contain the longest list(s).'.format(', '.join(names))

# => Book 3, 4 contain the longest list(s).
```

Comment: My program generates 4 lists containing a random amount of elements. When I use this code, it doesn't compare them properly and outputs the wrong longest list (when two lists are of the same length, it outputs those two lists even though there may be another one that is longer)

Comment: @Gaze, I added an example (code is same, only list variable is changed). According to that, there is no problem you described.

Comment: I didn't put my full code here, but this is an example of what's going on in my code

Comment: @Gaze, I added another code that handle nested list (`books` in the code).